# an XQuery query that calculates the average of the grades of each course

Tags: xml, xquery

an XQuery query that calculates the
average of the grades of each course, how i can do?

```
    <?xml-stylesheet href="class3.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?><school>
    <student><name>Jack T</name>
    <course title="INF8430" note="78"/>
    <course title="INF1030" note="69"/>
    <course title="INF1230" note="85"/></student>
    <student><name>Marty L</name>
    <course title="INF8430" note="95"/>
    <course title="INF1030" note="82"/>
    <course title="INF1230" note="77"/></student>
    <student><name>Ben L</name>
    <course title="INF9430" note="59"/>
    <course title="INF1030" note="78"/>
    <course title="INF1230" note="79"/></student>
    </school>
```

i do this but dnst work:

```
     for $s in distinct-values(doc("tesst.xml")//course/@title)
    return
     avg(doc("tesst.xml")//course[@title=$s]/@note)
     <course title="{$s},"></course>
```

to get this:

```
<maliste>
       <cours sigle="INF8430">85</cours>
       <cours sigle="INF1030">76.66666666666667</cours>
       <cours sigle="INF1230">81.5</cours>
       <cours sigle="INF9430">39</cours>
    </maliste>
```

an XQuery query that calculates the
average of the grades of each course, how i can do?

Comment: Don't tell us it doesn't work, tell us how it fails.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a typical grouping/aggregation problem:

```
<malist>
{
  for $course in //course
  group by $title := $course/@title
  return
    <cours sigle="{$title}">{format-number(avg($course/@note), '0.00')}</cours>
}
</malist>
```

In XQuery, grouping results might be in any order, if you want to preserve the input order use e.g.

```
<malist>
{
  for $course at $p in //course
  group by $title := $course/@title
  order by $p[1]
  return
    <cours sigle="{$title}">{format-number(avg($course/@note), '0.00')}</cours>
}
</malist>
```

Comment: <cours sigle="INF8430">86.50</cours>
<cours sigle="INF1030">76.33</cours>
<cours sigle="INF1230">80.33</cours>
<cours sigle="INF9430">59.00</cours>   i found this, but the average is not good. soorry to ask but how i can do it plz

Comment: @david9999, I don't understand what you complain about. The values you showed in your question don't seem to be the right values e.g. there is a single `<course title="INF9430" note="59"/>`, I don't see why the average would be `<cours sigle="INF9430">39</cours>`.

Comment: soryy my bad, my mystak. you right. thx very much